# Law of conservation of momentum and interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conservation-laws, interference, double-slit-experiment

There are two guns `a` and `b` that emit electrons simultaneously. Electrons meet at a point `с` and scatter in opposite directions with conservation of momentum. Passing through the double slits `S1` and `S3`, they interfere, which creates interference patterns on screens `S2` and `S4`. If we install the detector on slit `e`, then the interference pattern will disappear on screen `S2`.

The question is, what will we see on screen `S4`?

[image]

**Updated:**

This question is rather a paradox.

On the one hand, if the momentum of the electrons is conserved, then as soon as the detector is installed on the slit `e`, the interference pattern should instantly disappear on the screen `S4`, which allows information to be transmitted faster than the speed of light.

On the other hand, if the interference pattern does not disappear, then the momentum of the electrons is not conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On screen 4 you will still see "interference", as with photons each particle/wave will determine its own path (per Dirac, Feynman and QM) and all electrons going to the right have the option of going thru either unmodified slit which is the necessary requirement for "interference". To the left where for the slit that is modified and assuming every electron interacts with the detector, there will no pattern (possibly a very faint single slit pattern for the electrons that pass d).

Momentum is still conserved in the initial collision and additional momentum can/will be transferred to the slit at that interaction as well.

Comment: Could you please explain more about conservation of momentum? For example, if one electron is detected passing through the gap `e`, what will happen to the second electron?

Comment: And what "photons" do you mean?

Comment: By saying photons I am making an analogy because most of the double slit experiments were done with light (photons) due to simplicity/history and much fewer DSE experiments were done with electrons (expense apparatus required).  Both experiments showed the wave nature with the double slits. For the wave nature (the "interference") to occur all that is required is to be able to direct the matter (or photons) towards the slits so that the matter has a choice .... for the matter that passes the slits and hits the detector the interference is observed. Photons and electrons behave the same.

Comment: Momentum is important but also important the fact that matter was able to show its wave properties .... and this seems vey mysterious.  But if we consider that all matter only interacts initially via the EM field, specifically electrons in atoms/molecules are the first to encounter each other and then we further consider that the EM field is theorized to only work with photons and virtual photons it is possible to imagine that wave properties arise.

Comment: So don't you know what will happen to the second electron? I mean, what experiment will show.

Comment: So at "e" the electron will interact with the detector after the slits which gives it "new" wave properties, these new wave properties have nothing to do with the slits ... the electron just goes to the screen more freely, i.e. no interference.  The other companion electron is traveling towards the 2 slits and has to make a choice .... because it sees the effects of 2 slits (no detector) it will contribute to the interference pattern.

Comment: That is, if detectors are also installed on slots `f` and `g`, then the probability of detecting the second electron on them will be equiprobable?
It follows from this that if the double slits `S1` and `S3` are removed altogether, then the electrons can put dots on the screens `S2` and `S4` not on opposite sides of the point `c` (not symmetrical)?

Comment: I think the way your experiment is set one electron will always go right and the other left if they are in collision. Therefore you will always have one detection on the right and one detection on the left.  But at the screen the interference patterns  only show when the slit pairs have no detectors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136915/discussion-between-vitaliy-and-physicsdave).